# Pandoc Markdown to Markdown - Prevent adding backslash characters

Tags: parsing, text, markdown, pandoc, editing

I am using Pandoc to export from Markdown to Markdown to convert inline links to reference links. In this process Pandoc additionally adds many `\` backslash characters before special characters.

Is there a way I could prevent this additional behaviour of new `\`?

---

**Example**: `The price is $100.` becomes `The price is \$100.` after running Pandoc once, and it keeeps on adding `\`, next time it becomes `The price is \\$100.` and then `The price is \\\$100.`

---

Command Used:

```
PandocExtension="-f markdown-auto_identifiers-all_symbols_escapable -t markdown-all_symbols_escapable-auto_identifiers+table_captions-multiline_tables-simple_tables-grid_tables+pipe_tables-fenced_code_blocks-fenced_code_attributes+backtick_code_blocks"
PandocOption="-s --wrap=none --columns 10000 --atx-headers  --reference-links --tab-stop 2"
pandoc ${PandocOption} ${PandocExtension} "${Source}" -o "${Output}"
```

Comment: Could you give an example? That would also make it easier to understand what part of the link you are referring to (the link description, it's target, link title,..).

Comment: @tarleb Please see the update in the question

Comment: Short answer: don't disable the *all_symbols_escapable* extension when reading: `-f markdown-auto_identifiers+all_symbols_escapable`. Classic Markdown does not allow to backslash-escape dollars. BTW, this is not the output I'm seeing, which pandoc version are you using?

Comment: `pandoc 2.5
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.1.2, skylighting 0.7.4`

Comment: I thought that `-all_symbols_escapable` would prevent all symbols to be escapable.  Thereby, preventing backslashes to be appended for all symbols. Am I wrong? But I will try what you suggested.